# Задать цикл для изменения значений атрибутов пунктов списка

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Есть список с li элементами. Каждый элемент расположен левее на 5px, чем предыдущий.
Сделала банальным указанием смещения для каждого пункта.
Но можно ли как-то обойти это и сделать цикл, чтобы каждый элемент был левее на 5px чем предыдущий?
Не знакома с jquery, но по фантазии набросала код, примерно такой (нерабочий):

```
$('.li-class').css("margin-left",function(i,value){
  for (i=1, i<li:last-child,i++){
     return margin-left(value) -=5px;
     }
  });
```

Возможно ли это осуществить с помощью цикла и какими средствами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('li').each(function(i){
  $(this).css({'margin-left': i*(-5)+ 'px'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: у метода css есть перегрузка позволяющая обойтись без прямого вызова each

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#x').click(function(){
 $("ul li").each(function(i, item){
    $(item).css("margin-left", i*5 + "px")
 })
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2222222</li>
  <li>2222222</li><li>2222222</li>
  <li>2222222</li>
  <li>2222222</li>
 
  <li>2222222</li>
  <li>2222222</li>
  <ul>
    
    <button id="x">Click me</button>
```